# Executing several Webpages (Razor) in parallel

Tags: razor, parallel-processing, thread-safety

Im loading up and executing my .cshtml files like this

```
var webPage = WebPage.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_relativeFilePath);

var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var startPage = StartPage.GetStartPage(webPage, "_PageStart", new[] { "cshtml" });
var pageContext = new WebPageContext(httpContext, webPage, startPage);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
{
   webPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(pageContext, writer);
}

string output = sb.ToString().Trim();
```

Now, since (in my world), each .cshtml file is a self-contained unit, i can have above code running N number of times in parallel, but in rare occasion it blows up with the exception below.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at System.Web.WebPages.TemplateStack.Pop(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
```

If i disable parallelization and run all the .cshtml files one by one, i can't trigger the exception. That makes me wonder if some inner workings of WebPages are not thread-safe, that each call to `ExecutePageHierarchy` somehow accesses some non-unique value in the current `HttpContext`

Answer (score 4):

The HttpContext and other ASP.NET intrinsic objects are generally not thread-safe for multiple consumers.  If your goal is just to use the Razor templating engine to process multiple things in parallel, I believe you can do this, since Razor itself doesn't have a direct dependency on anything in ASP.NET.  But once you involve .cshtml (System.Web.WebPages), you're unfortunately limited by ASP.NET's intrinsics at that point.

Comment: some digging revealed that that the TemplateStack is stored with a static key in HttpContext.Items and is the reason why this exception is thrown. A workaround could be to subclass the HttpContextWrapper isolate the Items property, so each of my parallel iterations will have its own unique stack. Would that work?

Comment: @Pauli that might work but it would be very, very unsupported. What you'd be doing is digging into the ASP.NET internals and slightly changing how they work, so the results are unpredictable, and could very well break with the slightest patch/change/upgrade to the system. As such, I do not recommend this approach. CSHTML pages are just not meant to be executed in parallel within the same request.

Answer (score 1):

Just for someone else seeing this thread. 
I did a minimal implementation of the abstract classes HttpContextBase and HttpRequestBase. I then feed new instances of these classes instead of the real ones when I want to render a viewPage. (Reason I have not used a templating framework is that I have not found a thread safe one yet, tips anyone?)

```
 public class MockRequest : HttpRequestBase
{
    public override bool IsLocal { get { return false; } }
}

public class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase
{
    private readonly IDictionary _items = new Hashtable();

    public override HttpRequestBase Request { get { return new MockRequest(); } }

    public override IDictionary Items { get { return _items; } }
}
```